# Delete element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have JavaScript code which allows me to add more input value field on fly.

Now I want to add functionality which allows me to `delete` field or element.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            fields = 0;
            function addInput() {
                var con = document.getElementById('text');
                if(fields != 10)
                {
                    con.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br></br>Study: <input type=\"text\" name=\"study[]\">Bug: <input type=\"text\" name=\"bug[]\"> BuildFile: <input type=\"text\" name=\"bname[]\" size=\"40\"> WAR File: <input type=\"text\" name=\"wname[]\" size=\"50\"><br />");

                    fields += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    con.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br />Only 10 instances allowed.");
                    document.form.add.disabled=true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
...
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add more Builds" />
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried following and it works but its removing all elements i want to remove just last one or specific one.

```
function remove() {
  element = document.getElementById('text');
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element)

}

<input type="button" value="Remove Element" onClick="remove('parent','child');">
```

Comment: Please ask a question and show us what you've tried as far as a `deleteInput()` attempt.

Comment: element = document.getElementById('text');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element); ?

Comment: @caleb.breckon - I am not javascript expert so it would be good if you put some light on your syntax

Comment: @Satish What is the element with the id "text"? I don't see it anywhere in your code. Additionally, why don't you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the relevant HTML and javascript so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** library to do this.

```
function deleteAllInputs() {
    $('#text').find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    })
}
```

Look at this example, it may help you: **http://jsfiddle.net/Bu4Jh/**.

You can wrap the elements into a div to delete them in one pass.

Comment: I have tried your code which is not working :( but why did you use delete all? I want to delete specific input field, how to do that?

Comment: You need to include jQuery in the header and it works. Your question did not mention that.

Comment: Check i have edited my question